# Problema de escalado con visual studio 2022 windows form c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, formularios, aplicación-escritorio, visual-studio-2022

Quisiera ayuda con un problema que me presenta visual studio 2022, la cuestión esta en que yo hice un sistema en un computador con pantalla de escala recomendada de 100% pero cuando abro el sistema en un computador con escala de pantalla recomendada de 125%, el diseño del sistema se "daña", los controles no aparecen en la posición que tienen que estar y el tamaño también es diferente lo que hace que el sistema no se aprecie.

Comment: Prueba cambiar la propiedad del formulario `AutoScaleMode = Dpi`

Comment: Funciono con uno, pero en otros no funciona. En el otro formulario, he probado todas las opciones de **AutoScaleMode**, y siempre se distorsionan, También pasa que si yo abro el sistema en escala 100% y luego la cambio a escala 125% sin cerrar el sistema, el sistema se ve bien, pero si lo cierro y lo abro después de pasar a escala 125% se distorsiona.

Comment: ¿Puedes pasar capturas de antes y después? ¿Hay algún control diferente respecto el que funciona o tienen algún control en común los que fallan?   ¿Tienes controles de librerías externas a Microsoft, en caso de ser así que librerías son y que controles utilizas de ellas? ¿Controles modificados?